# Set a monitoring alert for all the slots of an azure app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots, azure-monitoring

The title says it all.

I have some azure apps with 3 to 4 deployment slots each, I want to set monitoring alerts for server errors for all of them by making a somekind of global alert rule instead of define a rule for each slot and app.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Monitor alerts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/monitoring-overview-alerts/) are limited to one single Azure resource only.
If you like to go deeper and define alert rules for multiple Azure resources, you can use [Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/log-analytics-overview/) to collect data from several Azure resources and create one alert rule for multiple services.

In a nutshell:

1. Stream data from Azure monitor to Log Analytics into the OMS workspace, see [Data sources in log analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/log-analytics-data-sources/)
   [image]
2. Create and [alert in Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/log-analytics-alerts/) once
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

As we know, we could [use the Azure portal, PowerShell or the Command Line Interface etc to create alerts rule](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-alerts-portal/) to monitor Azure resource metrics, events or logs. And we need to specify the **Resource ID** for the resource that we want to set and alert for, and different resources with different Resource ID, so we could not create a global alerts rule for monitoring all of our web apps and slots.

Resource ID may look like this.

Web app:

"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/YourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/websitename"

Web app slot:

"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/YourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/websitename/slots/slotname"